# Apply left join in 2 lists based on multiple conditions C#

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 data sets with me as follow :

```
{
        "email": "xyz@yopmail.com",
        "courseId": "111",
        "courseName": "Using Microsoft Azure Database Services",
        "progress": 39,
        "minutesWatched": 5.166667,
        "lastActivity": "2022-01-06T00:00:00Z"
}
```

and

```
{
        "email": "xyz@yopmail.com",
        "courseId": "111",
        "courseName": "Using Microsoft Azure Database Services",
        "startDate": "2022-07-31T00:00:00Z",
        "completeDate": null,
        "completed": false
}
```

I want to left join the two lists on the basis of emailId and courseId. From the first list I want to extart all the info and from the second I want to get the values for `completeDate` `completed` and `startedDate`. This is what I am using

```
var result = (from x in courseProgress
                          from y in courseCompletion
                              .Where(y => y.email.Equals(x.email, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) && y.courseId.Equals(x.courseId, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
                          select new XYZ
                          {
                              email = x.email,
                              courseId = x.courseId,
                              courseName = x.courseName,
                              progress = x.progress,
                              minutesWatched = x.minutesWatched,
                              startDate = y.startDate,
                              completeDate = y.completeDate.HasValue ? y.completeDate : DateTime.MinValue,
                              completed = y.completed,
                              lastActivity = x.lastActivity
                          }).ToList();
```

However, I want to apply a left join so that I can get records from first list even when there is no matching record from the second list.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)

Comment: Use `DefaultIfEmpty`

Comment: Tried that. Ran into some different error.

Comment: "some different error" means what exactly? Please also show the code you tried.